# Change value of enum's variable as per the latest in swift

Tags: swift, variables, enums

am new to swift PL. I have doubt regarding a new implementation. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Desc : I have an enum in a class with multiple API URLs. Those API URL are accessing a variable - `BaseURL` declared in that same class. I want to change value of that `BaseURL` from another class but enum variables are fetching the same old value.

**class : API.swift**

```
var BaseURL = "xyz.com/"

enum apis {
  static let login = BaseURL + "login"
}
```

**class : ViewControllerA.swift**

```
func switchBaseURL() {
  BaseURL = "abc.com/"

  // Call API Method
  self.callAPI()
}

func callAPI(){
  print("\(apis.login)") // Result is : xyz.com/login
}
```

I want to implement a solution that would enable to switch the value of `BaseURL` anytime from any class such that enum fetches the latest value set in BaseURL everytime.

Comment: Make `BaseURL` as `static` type so that when updating Url in it will be saved for further use

Comment: @Kudos i tried using `class a {  static var BaseURL = String() }`. Then assigned value as : `a.BaseURL = "xyz.com/"` in `AppDelegate.swift`. Switch the value as - `a.BaseURL = "abc.com/"` in `ViewControllerA.swift`. Still same results.

Comment: Good. So after changing the value Are you again calling `self.callAPI()`?

Comment: @Kudos yes. the `switchBaseURL()` method performs changing the URL and calling `self.callAPI()`. Is it due to the `static` used in enum which is making it to store the previous value only and not computing the value again when changed ?

Comment: I think YES. Remove Static from `static let login = BaseURL + "login"` and replace `let` with `var` and try

Comment: Off topic but I think it would be better if baseUrl is a property in your API class rather than a global variable and that you change it using a function of that class and/or when making an external call with the class.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `login` is declared `static`. It means that it's only computed once. Not to mention, it's also `let`.

One of the things that you can do without drastically changing your design is to modify the `login` property to be computed every time it's accessed:

```swift
var baseURL = "xyz.com/"

enum API {
    static var login: String { baseURL + "login" }
}

print(API.login) // xyz.com/login

baseURL = "abc.com/"
print(API.login) // abc.com/login
```

The code adopted to the original snippet:

```swift
var baseURL = "xyz.com/"

enum API {
    static var login: String { baseURL + "login" }
}

func switchBaseURL() {
    baseURL = "abc.com/"
    callAPI()
}

func callAPI(){
    print("\(API.login)")
}

switchBaseURL() // Prints abc.com/login
```

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is somewhere else then. The code snippet in the answer is copied directly from Xcode Playground. Comments are exactly the console output. Just try to copy this snippet to your own Playground and run it – you'll see. I also added one more snippet, which adopts your methods call.

Comment: @HemantGarg this solution is working fine. i think your problem is different or you may not explain properly

Comment: Yes i have also tried this solution in playground. Its works ok. But i create 2 separate files and try the same thing. It doesn't gives valid response. When i use class files `API.swift` and `ViewControllerA.swift` it doesn't gives expected results

Comment: I'm pretty much sure you're having some other kind of problem there now. You can share essential code snippets if you like, we'll try to figure it out.